# Round to a given number in Python

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I'm running a simulation in which people age in small (month, week) increments. However, I have hazards in non-consistent age-intervals.  Is there an simple/efficient way to round my age at any time to the nearest age-group (for the purpose of extracting the hazards for that age?

```
age_groups = np.array([0, .01, .1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40])
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your hazard age intervals? It sounds like you want to just identify which hazard groups each individual fits into, but I can't quite tell from the information you've given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have ages such as .5, 5, 6, 10, 32, 32.5, ect. that need to fall into the age_groups array you have.

This is an easy one-liner :)

Assuming you have:

```
age_groups = np.array([0, .01, .1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40])
age = .5
```

The solution is:

```
nearest_age = age_groups[(np.abs(age_groups-age)).argmin()]
```

Put that line into a function, passing it the age_groups array and the age you want rounded :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't vectorize, unless you broadcast and create a big array, unutbu's answer with searchsorted is the efficient vectorized version.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to group the ages into bins defined by `age_groups`.
Then you can find which age range each age falls into using [np.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

ages=np.array([0,0.05,1,3,5,10,13,19,25,35])

age_groups = np.array([0, .01, .1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40])

index=age_groups.searchsorted(ages,side='left')
for age,nearest_age in zip(ages,age_groups[index]):
    print('{a} --> {n}'.format(a=age,n=nearest_age))
```

yields

```
0.0 --> 0.0
0.05 --> 0.1
1.0 --> 5.0
3.0 --> 5.0
5.0 --> 5.0
10.0 --> 10.0
13.0 --> 15.0
19.0 --> 20.0
25.0 --> 25.0
35.0 --> 35.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to clusterize these elements, probably with the [k-mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm, here are some answers: [Python k-means algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545606/python-k-means-algorithm)