# Clustering using k-means in python

Tags: python, tags, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have a document d1 consisting of lines of form user_id tag_id.
There is another document d2 consisting of tag_id tag_name
I need to generate clusters of users with similar tagging behaviour.
I want to try this with k-means algorithm in python.
I am completely new to this and cant figure out how to start on this.
Can anyone give any pointers?

Do I need to first create different documents for each user using d1 with his tag vocabulary?
And then apply k-means algorithm on these documents?
There are like 1 million users in d1. I am not sure I am thinking in right direction, creating 1 million files ?

Answer (score 4):

Since the data you have is binary and sparse (in particular, not all users have tagged all documents, right)? So I'm not at all convinced that k-means is the proper way to do this.

Anyway, if you want to give k-means a try, have a look at the variants such as **k-medians** (which won't allow "half-tagging") and convex/spherical k-means (which supposedly works better with distance functions such as cosine distance, which seems a lot more appropriate here).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Jacob Eggers, you have to denormalize the data to form the matrix which is a sparse one indeed. 
Use SciPy package in python for k means. See

[Scipy Kmeans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans)

for examples and execution.
Also check [Kmeans in python (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545606/python-k-means-algorithm) for more information in python kmeans clustering.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to denormalize the data so that you have one file like this:

```
userid tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 ....
0001   1    0    1    0    ....
0002   0    1    1    0    ....
0003   0    0    1    1    ....
```

Then you need to loop through the k-means algorithm. Here is matlab code from the ml-class:

```
% Initialize centroids
centroids = kMeansInitCentroids(X, K);
for iter = 1:iterations
    % Cluster assignment step: Assign each data point to the
    % closest centroid. idx(i) corresponds to cˆ(i), the index 
    % of the centroid assigned to example i
    idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids);

    % Move centroid step: Compute means based on centroid
    % assignments
    centroids = computeMeans(X, idx, K);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For sparse k-means, see the examples under
[scikit-learn clustering](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/clustering.html).
About how many ids are there, how many per user on average,
how many clusters are you looking for ? Even rough numbers,
e.g. 100k ids, av 10 per user, 100 clusters,
may lead to someone who's done clustering in that range
(or else to back-of-the-envelope "impossible").

[MinHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash)
may be better suited for your problem than k-means;
see chapter 3, Finding Similar Items,
of [Ullman, Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds);
also [SO questions/tagged/similarity+algorithm+python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/similarity+algorithm+python).